# How to bring one dialogue popup on top of another in material Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have two dialogue popups implemented using Angular Material Mat Dialog. How ever always the second opened dialogue will come on top of the first.  In the picture since the Student popup opened first, it will always be behind the teacher popup.

[image]

Is there a way I could bring the selected, in this case when I click on Student Dialogue bring it to the front, same should happen if I click on the Teacher Popup

Comment: Please add a complete and reproducible example, f.e. a StackBlitz to get you helped. Read also [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The pattern of having 2 or more dialogs open at the same time is not recommended and likely indicates bad design. In any case, I your desired behavior does not come OOTB.